# How to link a module in asp.net, C# web application in all forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way for me to link my module in all of my form i'm using c# app and this is my code. This is actually a notification bell that will notify users if he/she has/have notifications. I already linked it on homepage how am i able to do that in all other pages

```
 private void systemNotificationREXS(HomePage module)
    {
        TextBox Username = (TextBox)module.FindControl("Hide_user");
        Label Fullname = (Label)module.FindControl("userfullname");
        Label notifLabel = (Label)module.FindControl("notifLabel");
        using (con = new SqlConnection(EXCUSESLPCON))
        {
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("SYSTEMNOTIFICATIONEXSLIP", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userfullname", Fullname.Text);
                con.Open();
                using(adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using(dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        adp.Fill(dt);
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++ )
                        {
                            int notifcount = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["notifcount"].ToString());
                            string modulename = dt.Rows[i]["modulename"].ToString();
                            string modulebody = modulename + "Body";
                            string moduleLabel = modulename + "Label";
                            Label namebox = (Label)module.FindControl(modulename);
                            if (notifcount > 0)
                            {
                                namebox.Visible = true;
                                namebox.Text = notifcount.ToString();
                                module.FindControl(modulebody).Visible = true;

                                try
                                {
                                    module.FindControl(moduleLabel).Visible = true;
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    notifLabel.Visible = false;
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                namebox.Visible = false;
                                module.FindControl(modulebody).Visible = false;
                                try
                                {
                                    module.FindControl(moduleLabel).Visible = false;
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    notifLabel.Visible = false;
                                }


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    internal void notificationSystemREXS(string fullname, string hide_user, HomePage modulename)
    {
        systemNotificationREXS(modulename);
    }
```

Code to linked on homepage:

```
  private void systemNotificationREXS()
    {
        Notification moduleacc = new Notification();
        moduleacc.notificationSystemREXS(userfullname.Text, Hide_user.Text, this);
    }
```

Comment: what block you from doing the same thing to other page?

Comment: you should not have the class function dependent on the WebPage or it's controls. It should be able to work independently. You should have he method accept values in native datatypes such as class, string, integer etc and also should return values that way. And you should use the returned values to whatever you want to do with them such as display to some label etc.

Comment: What is `HomePage` here?

Comment: @Jacky it won't allow me to link  cause it's dependent on homepage see my private void, "(HomePage module)" My problem is, I have no Idea how to create an independent class cause i don't know the rules of class library in C#  in which will allow me to link on every webform that i  created

Answer (score 0):

Your method does very simple job, but you have made it complicated and over dependent on the module and other stuff.

The method should return only the notification data for the user and let the caller of the method to decide what to do with the data.

Consider doing following.

```
public class NotificationData
{
     public int NotificationCount {get;set;}
     public int ModuleName {get;set;}
}

public  class NotificationService
{
    public static List<NotificationData> GetNotificationData(string username)
    {
        var notificationList = new List<NotificationData>();
        using (con = new SqlConnection(EXCUSESLPCON))
        {
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("SYSTEMNOTIFICATIONEXSLIP", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userfullname", Fullname.Text);
                con.Open();
                using(adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using(dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++ )
                        {
                            var notification = new NotificationData();
                            notification.NotificationCount = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["notifcount"].ToString());
                             notification.ModuleName = dt.Rows[i]["modulename"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return notificationList
    }
}
```

Now you should use this method from whichever page you want as following.

Let say you want to use it from HomePage. So you may write following code in `Page_Load` event of HomePage. (I am assuming here that `HomePage` is a web page and it has all the controls loaded before this code gets executed).

```
Label userNameLabel = (Label)this.FindControl("userfullname");
var userName = userNameLabelText;
var notificationList = NotificationService.GetNotificationData(userName);

foreach(var notification in notificationList)
{
    var modulename = notification.ModuleName;
    var notifcount = notification.Count;
    string modulebody = modulename + "Body";
    string moduleLabel = modulename + "Label";

    Label namebox = (Label)this.FindControl(modulename);
    if (notifcount > 0)
    {
        namebox.Visible = true;
        namebox.Text = notifcount.ToString();
        this.FindControl(modulebody).Visible = true;
        try
        {
            this.FindControl(moduleLabel).Visible = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            notifLabel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        namebox.Visible = false;
        this.FindControl(modulebody).Visible = false;
        try
        {
            this.FindControl(moduleLabel).Visible = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            notifLabel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Got it, i'll try to do this  soon i get home and give an update. Thankyou